# Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The new session command returned a value ('Unknown error') that is not a valid JSON object

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

#### Problem

When I try to run the application in the integrated development environment (**Jetbrains Rider**) an error occurs:

```
[15:14:06.969] - Listening on http://127.0.0.1:43237/ [15:14:06.969] - Listening on http://[::1]:43237/ Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The new session command returned a value ('Unknown error') that is not a valid JSON object.
```

---

#### Source Code

```
    IWebDriver  driver = new EdgeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com");

    IWebElement usernameInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='username']"));
    IWebElement passwordInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']"));


    usernameInput.SendKeys("YourUsername");
    passwordInput.SendKeys("YourPassword");
```

---

#### Properties of the NuGet Packages used

`Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver` - Version `87.0.669`

`Selenium.WebDriver` - Version `4.0.0-alpha07`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Edge browser are you using? You need to use the same `Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver` version with your Edge browser version. For example, I use Edge 87.0.664.47, then I need to use `Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver` - Version 87.0.664.47.

Besides, you need to use this line in the code: `edgeOptions.UseChromium = true`.

You can try the following code, it can work well on my side:

```
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
IWebElement usernameInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='username']"));
IWebElement passwordInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']"));
usernameInput.SendKeys("YourUsername");
passwordInput.SendKeys("YourPassword");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
driver.Close();
```